# Whats the difference between compiling from a makefile and from the command line?

Tags: scala, compilation, path, makefile

I have the following really strange Problem: I wrote a makefile for a multilanguage java/scala project. (I tried to make a ant-buildfile working, but no chance to get this working ever ...) When doing 'make', I get the following:

scalac  -d ... -cp ... -sourcepath ... ... myFile.scala
myFile.scala:28: error: ModuleX is not a member of project.module

import project.module.ModuleX

Now copying the command 'scalac' that appears on the screen when make is executed and inserting it in a bash shell (the same bash shell I executed 'make' before) leads to ... NO FAILURE. It just compiles without error. So what the hell is going on there? What information has the shell that are not available for 'make'? (ALL PATHS ARE GIVEN AS ABSOLUTE PATHS, none is given relatively. But -sourcepath has two arguments, could this cause a problem?) Help, its a really strange thing ... :(

Comment: Probably has something either to do with your current directory or your environment variables.  Try `bash -c 'scalac...'` and see if that works (from the directory where your makefile is); that generally gives you an environment similar to what `make` sees.

Comment: I will suggest just switch to SBT (Simple Build Tool) as your build tool, it could handle Scala/Java mix project more easily, make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

You have a -sourcepath in the example line you included. That probably isn't working in the way you expect.

See this bug and how it manifests itself
[make -sourcepath into something less visible](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4909)